# ios swift parse: reload tableView works on updates but not when adding new items

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i am using these lines in my tableViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When I **edit** data and return to the tableView, I can see the changes I've done because the reload seems to happen.

When I **add** new data (I am using the same save method as on edit) I return to the previous tableView but the new entries don't appear. But they are saved within parse for sure.

I wonder, why there is a difference between add and edit? When using the same code with both? And using the same IBAction for saving?

This is my save method:

```
@IBAction func saveNewCard(sender: AnyObject) {

    // set up data
    self.cardObject["front"] = self.frontTextArea.text
    self.cardObject["back"] = self.backTextArea.text
    self.cardObject.setObject(cardSetObject, forKey: "cardset") // Setting the pointer

    println(cardObject)

    self.cardObject.saveEventually { (success, error) -> Void in

        if(error == nil){

            println(success)

            // Return to table view
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

        }else{
            println(error.userInfo)
        }
    }

}
```

In `viewDidLoad()` I decide wether its a new (add) or an existing (edit) Object:

```
var cardObject: PFObject! // if edit - I get the object transported via segue
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (self.cardObject != nil){

        // edit
        self.navigationItem.title = "Edit"
        self.frontTextArea.text = self.cardObject["front"] as String
        self.backTextArea.text = self.cardObject["back"] as String


    }else{

        // add new
        self.navigationItem.title = "Add"
        self.cardObject = PFObject(className:"Card")
    }
}
```

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CardTableViewCell

        // card object
        let cardObject: PFObject = self.cardObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
        var front = cardObject["front"] as String
        var back = cardObject["back"] as String
        cell.frontLabel.text = front
        cell.backLabel.text = back


        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: viewDidAppear: is not called when you pop a presented viewcontroller.

Comment: But funny... Why do I see then my edited changes then? Any why not the added?

Comment: Added changes will not reflect until the cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called.

Comment: When I add a println() to  `viewDidAppear ` I can see it every time I return to the view (after save and after edit). So I think that it's not true that `viewDidAppear ` isn't called.

Comment: Show the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Also add the other data source methods.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following if you are using navigation controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    if([[segue destinationViewController] class] == [self class]){
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```